# Opengl transparent cube faces

Tags: c++, opengl, transparent, zbuffer

I am drawing transparent cubes,which share vertices, in a grid(Windows 7 VC++ VS 2012). Problem is when i rotate the picture i see strange visual effect in planes where cubes touch each other. Is this effect because of that reason only and i need to remove the shared faces? Or there is some other trick to it?

Does it have anything to do with face/orientation of the cube surface? btw i have tried a lot of these already but cant make it work perfectly.

Comment: Stuff like this needs a screenshot, but I suspect it's just simply how you have your depth buffer set up (i.e. your zNear and zFar values).

Comment: maybe it's z-fighting?

Answer (score 0):

If you assure a consistent process when defining triangle vertex numbering this issue can be avoided.  Typically you number vertices counter-clockwise  0, 1, 2  Doing this tells the OpenGL state machine which side is up.  Depending on your needs there is a GL flag you can set to color in or not front and/or back of such triangles ... let us know how you get on